# Opening a Base Url with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, audio, xmlhttprequest, web-audio-api

I'm using XMLHttpRequest to load an audio, and Web Audio Api to get the frequency of that audio to use for a visualizer. I am new to the concept, but what I've learned is that the second parameter "url" in XMLHttpRequest's open method must be in the same domain as the current document, a relative url (e.g audio-folder/music.mp3).

I want to open an audio from a third party website outside of the database (https://c1.rbxcdn.com/36362fe5a1eab0c46a9b23cf4b54889e), but of course, returns an error.

I assume the way is to save the audio from the base url into the database so the XMLHttpRequest can be sent, and then remove it once the audio's frequency has been calculated. But how exactly can I do this? I'm not sure where to start, or how efficient this is, so if you have advice then I'd love to hear it.

Here is the code I'm working with.

```
function playSample() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', 'example.mp3', true);
    request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    // When loaded decode the data
    request.onload = function() {
        // decode the data
        setupAudioNodes();
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
        // when the audio is decoded play the sound
        sourceNode.buffer = buffer;
        sourceNode.start(0);
        rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame(updateVisualization);
        }, function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
    };
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: Why are you using ajax request to fetch it?

Comment: `I assume the way is to save the audio from the base url` - If I understand what you're trying to say, you want to access a third party resource using a request to your domain?

Comment: `the second parameter "url" in XMLHttpRequest's open method must be in the same domain as the current document` - this is incorrect. However, to access a "cross origin resource", i.e. a resource on a third party site, that site must allow it (that's what CORS is about)

Comment: @JaromandaX When I try to access the third party resource using `request.open('GET', 'https://c1.rbxcdn.com/36362fe5a1eab0c46a9b23cf4b54889e');`, the onload event never gets fired, and errors when I do `request.send();`. I'm assuming it doesn't know what I'm trying to do. The resource website is a single audio/mpeg source.

Comment: that's because of CORS - check the browser developer tools console, you'll see an error regarding CORS headers (unless you use an inferior browser) - it's not that "it doesn't know what you're trying to do", the fact is, you're trying to use a third party resource in your webpage, and the third party does not allow you to use its resources in the way you are trying

Comment: @JaromandaX Okay, I see now. I get the following error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". I'm still allowed to play the audio through `var sound = new Audio(example); sound.play();`. Is there a way I can automatically download the resource into my own domain to use the Web Audio API on?

Comment: using *your* server you can